# Angular2 bind variable to the selector

Tags: angular

Havig

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bindNAMEhere',
    template: `

  {{name}}
    `
})
```

is there a way to bind into 'bindNAMEhere' some value !?

Answer (score 0):

The selector is static and can't be changed at runtime. There was an issue opened recently to support that though.

Comment: what do you mean 'selecting templates'?

Comment: You can't change the template at runtime.

Comment: I'd like to declare selector as any native html tag ex. input and to change its type dynamically like text or number, template is not so important here!
So the final source code will look like native html without any specific angular selectors!

Comment: Sorry, was on my phone and was a bit sloppy reading. It's the same with selector though. This can't be changed. There was an issue opened recently from an Angular team member  to support that.

Comment: What you can do though is to add a list of selectors where only one needs to match if this is of any help. I'm sure I saw that issue and a following discussion recently but can't find it just now.